# Tomcat SSL Error sec_error_unknown_issuer

Tags: tomcat, ssl, jira

i'm trying to secure my Jira Application with SSL. I've requested an certificate but it doesn't work - firefox returns "sec_error_unknown_issuer"

The fallowing steps i've done:

```
1) keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore sub_domain_tld.key -validity 360 -keysize 2048
2) keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -file sub_domain_tld.csr -keystore sub_domain_tld.key
3) keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate.crt -keystore sub_domain_tld.key
4) keytool -import -trustcacerts -file cert.cabundle -keystore sub_domain_tld.key
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: You should google "Tomcat SSL configuration". I found this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html and article from atlassian: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Running+JIRA+over+SSL+or+HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the comments of the jira page:

**Matthew Block**:

> Okay, after fighting this for a good day, I finally got it working
>   with my existing ssl certificate.  I have a *.
>   certificate with the cert and private keys in separate files.  After
>   several searches and trial and error, turns out you can just use the
>   openssl tool to create a PKCS12 keystore which contains your private
>   key and then tell JIRA to use that keystore.  This site
>   (https://wiki.systemsx.ch/display/ITDOC/Import+an+openssl+generated+key+into+a+tomcat+application)
>   was the most help for me.  But basically, here are the steps...
>   1.    If your key does not have a password (mine did not) create a DES encrypted version using the same password you plan to use for your
>   keystore... openssl rsa -in  -des -out keyout.pem
>   2.     Ensure you have a file containing the chain for your certificate, starting with your server certificate up to the root
>   certificat cat  []  > cert.pem
>   3.    Create the PKCS12 keystore containing both your private key and the public certificate chain.  Use the same password for the export as
>   you used for your private key openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey keyout.pem
>   -in cert.pem -out keystore.pkcs12
>   4.    Update the server.xml as noted above ensuring all of the following are defined... a.     keystoreFile (points to the
>   keystore.pkcs12 file you created above) b.    keystoreType="PKCS12" c.
>   keystorePass (the password you used above)